# Plupload in .NET - raising an error in the Plupload control

Tags: .net, plupload

I have an event handler for when an error is raised in Plupload:

```
Error: function(up, args) {
  // do something
}
```

How do I RAISE an error elsewhere in the code? I want to say `up.RaiseError("something is wrong etc")`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can manually trigger the error event:

```
up.trigger('Error', args);
```

where `args` can basically be anything you want. For consistency, `args` should be an object with 2 required keys `code` and `message`, and 2 optional keys `file` and `status`.